# Rcpp - Define a C++ function that takes an R function and an ellipsis argument

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, ellipsis

I have an R function `bar` that takes another R function `foo`, defined as follows:

```
foo <- function(x,y) x + y
bar <- function(foo, z, ...) z + foo(...)
```

A call to `bar` would be of the form:

```
bar(foo, 1,2,3)
```

Now with `foo` defined as above, I want to create a C++ version of `bar`. Here's what I've tried:

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction(
'
  double bar(Function foo, double z, ...) {
  return z + foo(...);
 }
 ')
```

This clearly doesn't work. What would be the right way to define this function in C++?

Thanks.

Comment: If you have `foo` and all of the arguments (`...`) available on the R side, why not just pass the result of `foo(...)` into the Rcpp function? Evaluating `foo(..)` from C++ is *always* going to be slower than evaluating `foo(...)` directly from the R side.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It might be easier to turn your ellipsis into a list before feeding it to Rcpp

```
bar <- function(foo, z, ...) {
   args <- list(...)
   bar_internal(foo, z, args)
}
```

And then your Rcpp function can simply take a `Rcpp::List` instead of ellipsis.

```
double bar_internal(Function foo, double z, List args){

}
```

Comment: Ellipsis use between C++ and R has _many_ problems or challenges in the Rcpp context as we are bound by `SEXP ,Call("someId", SEXP, SEXP, ...)`.  We have some attempts in the code (and then depends on whether you use C++98, or C++11 or later), but quite frankly your best bet is what @Jeroen suggests.  Just avoid the complication and move on.